# how long will take for an astronal travel in near lightspeed in his point of view

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, time-dilation, observers

I always had a question about relativity.
Suppose an astronaut in orbit Saturn just must reach earth fast as possible.

Your ship can travel at any speed between 0 and the speed of light.
the distance is 60 minutes in lightspeed. But if he travels near the 0.99c there will be an expansion of 8x time, which will make the travel last 8 hours.

If he travels at light speed, it will take all eternity to reach earth, so, he will "never" reach..
If he travels at 0c he will never reach either...

So, what is the best speed to get to the earth fast as possible?

Comment: You have got time-dilation the wrong way round.  A journey of 60 minutes, as seen by an observer on Earth ( or Saturn ) will take 60 / 8 or 7.5 minutes for a traveller travelling at .99 _c_.

Comment: And how long (for the traveler point of view) will take at lightspeed (1c). will it be zero?

Comment: You can't reach $c$.

Comment: Do you really believe that light from Saturn has never reached earth?

Comment: "What is the fas", can somebody please edit the title.

Comment: @pfnuesel  I understand we cannot reach c, but if we get 0.9999999999... c in earth point of view it will take 60 minutes ,but in the astronaut point of view. ... just some seconds, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an *Earth-bound* observer, it really doesn't differ much the time it takes to travel this distance with a velocity of *C* or *0.99C*. If propagating with *C* takes him/her *60 minutes,* (assuming you have calculated it correctly,) it is easy to see that *0.99C* will take him/her 60 minutes and 36 seconds. (unlike what you have claimed.) However, from his/her *own* stand of point, lengths will be *contracted* (or internal clocks will be *slowed* compared to Earth clocks) and he/she will reach Earth in a shorter period of time. In particular, he/she will be there instantaneously (again unlike what you have claimed) if *"sitting on a photon" (which is impossible)* and about *7 times shorter* than what it took him/her from the standpoint of an *Earth-boun*d observer if travelling with *0.99C.* (So instead of 60 minutes and 36 seconds, it will take *him/her* only 8 minutes and 33 seconds.)